# Cannot change color ion-fab-button, worked before ion-fab-list

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

Here is my code.

```
<ion-fab-button (click)="submitForm(aluno)" [ngClass]="!tudoOk ? 'disabled' : 'enabled'" (click)="!tudoOk ? mensagemErro() : ''">

.disabled {
  --background: #9CC0FF;
}

.enabled {
  color: "primary";
}
```

this worked before I put ion-fab-button inside ion-fab-list

```
<ion-fab-list side="top">
```

Anybody knows what could be wrong?

Comment: in your scss is the disabled/enabled class are inside a container ?

Comment: I checked your code in Ionic 4 and it is already working. Here you can check https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-agg6nf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Faction-sheet%2Faction-sheet.component.html

Comment: @M0ns1f no not inside a container; How do I put that?

Comment: @PraveenPatel your stackblitz doesn't reflect my code here's my code.
```
<ion-fab-list side="top">
          <ion-fab-button (click)="submitForm(aluno)" [ngClass]="!tudoOk ? 'disabled' : 'enabled'" (click)="!tudoOk ? mensagemErro() : ''">
            <ion-icon name="save"></ion-icon>
          </ion-fab-button>
          <ion-fab-button color="danger" (click)="excluirAluno(aluno)">
            <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
          </ion-fab-button>
        </ion-fab-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem!
I just had to change the css as this:

```
.disabled {
  --background: #9CC0FF;
  --color: #FFFFFF;
}

.enabled {
  --background: #3880FF;
  --color: #FFFFFF;
}
```